# configuración botones data bases con bootstrap 5

Tags: javascript, php, css, bootstrap, datatable

buenas tardes estimados.

Tengo el siguiente problema, no estoy pudiendo asignarle los colores de bootstrap 5 a los botones de Excel, PDF e Imprimir que se generan con Data Tables, simplemente quedan con un color gris los 3.
He incluído las librerías y asigné los atributos de bootstrap dentro de "className" en el script de databases pero parece no funcionar.
Agradezco si alguien me puede ayudar.

Copio el código:

css:

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">      
    <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.4/css/dataTables.bootstrap5.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.2/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.10.4/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-oS3vJWv+0UjzBfQzYUhtDYW+Pj2yciDJxpsK1OYPAYjqT085Qq/1cq5FLXAZQ7Ay" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Librerias:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>     
    </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-oP6HI9z1XaZNBrJURtCoUT5SUnxFr8s3BzRl+cbzUq8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.4/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.4/js/dataTables.bootstrap5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.2/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.2/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/0.1.53/build/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/0.1.53/build/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.2/js/buttons.flash.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.2/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
```

main.js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
            $('#paginacion').DataTable({        
                language: {
                        "lengthMenu": "Mostrar _MENU_ registros",
                        "zeroRecords": "No se encontraron resultados",
                        "info": "Mostrando _START_ de _END_ registros, en un total de _TOTAL_ registros",
                        "infoEmpty": "Mostrando registros del 0 al 0 de un total de 0 registros",
                        "infoFiltered": "(filtrado de un total de _MAX_ registros)",
                        "sSearch": "Buscar:",
                        "oPaginate": {
                            "sFirst": "Primero",
                            "sLast":"Último",
                            "sNext":"Siguiente",
                            "sPrevious": "Anterior"
                         },
                         "sProcessing":"Procesando...",
                    },
                //para usar los botones   
                responsive: "true",
                dom: 'Bfrtp',       
                buttons:[ 
                    {
                        extend:    'excelHtml5',
                        text:      '<i class="bi bi-file-earmark-excel-fill">Descargar Excel</i>',
                        titleAttr: 'Exportar a Excel',
                        className: 'btn btn-success'
                    },
                    {
                        extend:    'pdfHtml5',
                        text:      '<i class="bi bi-file-earmark-pdf-fill">Descargar PDF</i>',
                        titleAttr: 'Exportar a PDF',
                        className: 'btn btn-danger'
                    },
                    {
                        extend:    'print',
                        text:      '<i class="bi bi-printer-fill">Imprimir</i>',
                        titleAttr: 'Imprimir',
                        className: 'btn btn-info'
                    },
                ]           
            });     
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

encontré mi error.
El problema es que estaba agregando los estilos de Data Bases y me pasaba por arriba los estilos de Bootstrap.

La etiqueta que eliminé es la siguiente:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.2/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css">
```